# Qutation marks in American English for emphasis and bracketing: single or double?

Tags: american-english, mathematics, quotations, emphasis, quotation-marks

Suppose you write a mathematical text in American English that quotes from various sources (other literature and itself) and emphasizes and brackets stuff. You've already used up your font gimmicks (italic, bold, script, algorithms, etc.) for mathematical purposes (definitions, theorems, standard symbols, new symbols, variables, …). So to quote, emphasize, and bracket text you're left with single and double quotes, i.e., no «», aren't you?
As [Grant Barrett says](https://grantbarrett.com/a-hearty-endorsement-of-shout-quotes-scare-quotes-used-for-emphasis/), the shout/scare quotation marks are “appropriate when you have no other easy way to indicate emphasis.”

Now, given that double quotation marks are typically used for actual quotations (direct speech), would using single quotation marks be appropriate for EMPHASIS and BRACKETING? Or should the emphasized/bracketed stuff also go in double quotation marks?

Examples:

> Below,  stands for ‘*e*dges’. We are interested in properties of the form ‘in a yellow graph, a node is reachable from another node’. We examine the complexity of deciding such properties. Here, the expressions that do not depend on the size of  (‘constants’, to be hidden in the Landau notation) are unimportant. John Smith proved that “all yellow graphs [in ] are nonred” in [5].

> Thus, it suffices to prove just the equality term1 = term2. We do this by separating it into two inequalities:

> ‘⩽’: …

> ‘⩾’: …

> Now we proved term1 = term2. Examining the ‘then’ branch of the innermost if-then-else statement of Algorithm 1, we see that Algortihm 1 returns ‘true’ iff Algorithm 2 returns ‘nonempty’.

> Now we claim that the map : …  is well defined and a bijection:

> ‘ is well defined’: …

> ‘ is injective’: …

> ‘ is surjective’: …

Above, the double quotation marks are used for real quotations, and the single ones for emphasis and bracketing. Does this work for Americal English?  Any improvement suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be a question about writing mathematical/programming texts.   When you say *Algorithm 1 returns true **iif** Algorithm 2....etc.*  That is not standard English.  Why is *Algorithm* capitalized?  Is **iff** supposed to mean **if**?  Is there a reason to include the inline *iff* instead of a regular *if*? Does it add to the meaning?  I think this is a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/.  I'm sure the eggheads over there have an opinion or two.  Voting to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try the *article-writing* tag.  It seems to fit with your question.

Comment: Generally, punctuation for emphasis, etc. is not used in math texts.

Comment: @EllieK The tag *article-writing* doesn't exist (or doesn't show up if it exists). As for Algorithm 1, Algorithm 2, it's the same as Figure 1, Figure 2, except that the contents of the figures are not drawings but algorithms. In the real text, we have “Alg. 1” anf “Alg. 2”. “Iff” means “if and only if”.

Comment: @EllieK Instead, there is the tag “mathematics”, which I've just added. So, please remove your vote.

Comment: I think you would get more helpful answers on the mathematics site as your text does not read like the sort of mathematical texts with which I am familiar and I suspect that may be that you need to step back and ask a more general questions about writing mathematics.

Comment: @mdewey Certainly, the text in the OP is imaginary. Its parts are disconnected, have holes (…) and do not make much sense together. I am not as crazy as to put my real shit here. You understand? Or what is it that strikes you?

Comment: This is a web site for questions about learning English. This question has nothing to do with learning English, so it's off topic and I'm leaving it closed.

Comment: @gotube The usage of quotation marks is a language issue. The question is tagged with “mathematics”, exactly as any other question related to the subject.

Answer (score 4):

You should **not** use quotes for emphasis.

In your given examples you should *not use emphasis at all*!  The proper way to write this is to remove all single quotes, and replace them with nothing at all.

The use of emphasis is incorrect and the use of quotes for emphasis is wrong.

An acceptable use of quotes (single or double) can be in definitions of a new term or coining a new word

> We call a node 'inlinkable' if the linking restraints require the total weight of adjacent edges to be zero.

They can also be used to show a word is being used sarcastically, but sarcasm is not appropriate for a mathematical paper.

Comment: It's correct to say never use quotes for emphasis, but I don't believe his example is using them for emphasis.  His example is using them to directly quote definitions.

Comment: A very bad advice. I don't see how you'd make phrases such as “of the form in a yellow graph a node is reachable from another node” comprehensible without ANY emphasis.

Comment: That particular sentence is badly expressed, but I'm not here to do your proofreading.  You don't need any particular emphasis to express that, if you phrase it well. If you do want emphasis use font changes, or underline.  Never use quote marks for emphasis in English.

Comment: @JamesK No, the sentence “We are interested in properties of the form ‘in a yellow graph, a node is reachable from another node’.” is well-expressed and serves its purpose. Don't mess with my sentence unless you know what you are saying and why.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this website: https://www.really-learn-english.com/single-quotation-marks.html

> In **American English**, we usually use **double quotation marks** ( " " )
> first and single quotation marks ( ' ' ) second.
>
> Examples: My mother said, "The baby started talking today. The baby
> said, 'Mama.' "
>
> The teacher asked us, "How many of you have read the story 'The Brown
> Horse' in your textbook?"
>
> In **British English**, we ... usually [use] **single quotation marks** first and then
> double quotation marks.
>
> Examples: My mother said, 'The baby started talking today. The baby
> said, "Mama".'
>
> The teacher asked us, 'How many of you have read the story "The Brown
> Horse" in your textbook?'

This [TeX StackExchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63531/how-to-write-quotation-marks-in-math-environment) seems to imply that either quotations work in a math environment — so adhere to the British or American English quotations as you please.

Comment: That's NOT an English.SE thread but a TeX.SE thread. They care about HOW you typeset stuff once you've decided to typeset it. They don't care about WHAT you decide to typeset. My question, on the contrary, asks THE WHAT.

Comment: @GeekestGeek According to this answer, which I find to be completely correct, if you're writing in American English (as you say you are) then use double quotation marks everywhere. (You would use single quotation marks for quotations within quotations, but I do not see any such thing in your example text.)

Comment: @DavidK It is true that I care only about American English in this question. However, the examples of myaccon consider only the usage of quotation marks for direct speech. They are USELESS concerning the ACTUAL core of the question, namely, the usage of the quotation marks for EMPHASIS.

Comment: @GeekestGeek If you want *emphasis*, use italic or bold text. Your examples are not emphasis. The answer is telling you exactly how you should use quotation marks, provided that you use quotation marks at all. (Some of your examples could be written without them.)

Comment: @DavidK Font manipulations have already been ruled out. If you know for sure what could be written without quotation marks at all, please feel free to supply an answer…

Comment: The rules for British English are over-stated.  It is very common (and correct) to use double quotes first in British English, it is probalby more common than using single quotes first.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, quotation marks should *[never](https://leffcommunications.com/2017/03/10/how-to-use-quotation-marks/#:%7E:text=Do%20not%20use%20quotation%20marks,something%2C%20use%20boldface%20or%20italics.)* be used for emphasis.  As the link says, don't do it.  It's simply wrong.  It will never be interpreted as emphasis, but instead as sarcasm.

That said, the examples you used do not do this.  Emphasis is not the word you are looking for to describe the situation you are talking about.

> Below,  stands for ‘edges’.

We are not emphasizing "edges" here, we are defining  with an exact quoted definition.  This is correct.

> We are interested in properties of the form ‘in a yellow graph, a node is reachable from another node’.

Again, this is not emphasis, this is a definition.  Quotations are acceptable for definitions.

> (‘constants’, to be hidden in the Landau notation)

This is another definition.

> John Smith proved that “all yellow graphs [in ] are nonred” in [5].

This is a direct quotation.

Now, the use of double or single quotation marks is a style issue.  A style guide will tell you which you should use, but a general rule for using quotation marks inside of quotation marks is that whichever you use for the outside marks, use the opposite within.  But more important is to follow the style guide that governs the type of writing you are doing, whether that be the AMA style guide, the Chicago Manual of Style, the AP Style Guide, the MLA style guide, or your university or corporation's internal style guide.

A style guide might tell you to use more specific formatting.  I can *imagine* a style guide where definitions might be given single quotes, while direct quotations were given double quotes... but this would be *very* non-standard, and should only be used if you are told to do so in a specific domain for some reason.

Comment: ‘*e*dges’ is NOT a quotation. There is nothing quoted here from anywhere.

Comment: Similarly, ‘in a yellow graph, a node is reachable from another node’ is NOT a definition. We don't define any formal term here. Not even an informal phrase.

Comment: 'constants' is also NOT a definition. It's a term used with a slightly deviating meaning because we actually do not speak about constants such as 1,2, or 3.